# Wix Duplicate Symbol Error

Tags: wix

I am new to wix and I am having to add a dll to two separate folders as it is being used by two separate part in my application, but I am getting a duplicate symbol found error, how can I go about resolving this issue?

Answer (score 3):

First, create multiple component groups that target different installation locations. They contain the same DLLs/files. Then, give also a unique identifier for those DLLs inside the respective components with `Id` attribute.

For example:

```
<ComponentGroup Directory="FirstDirectory">
    <Component Id="Component1">
        <File Source="MyFile.dll" Id="MyFile.dll.InFirstDirectory" />
    </Component>
</ComponentGroup>
...
<ComponentGroup Directory="SomeElseDirectory">
    <Component Id="Component2">
        <File Source="MyFile.dll" Id="MyFile.dll.InSecondDirectory" />
    </Component>
</ComponentGroup>
```

Answer (score 2):

MSI does not support placing the same component into multiple locations. You have to make two components with the same source file.

Comment: I have created separate component files but I am not getting unresolved reference to symbol error.